# The Modal form which sends data by Pjax doesn't work - Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, pjax

I've got a setting module from a senior programmer and I encountered a problem as I'm new to Yii2. I’ll be brief, There are two controllers:

1-DefaultController.php

2-SettingCatController.php

On one hand, there is actionCreate (default/create) which will render the view of Setting page, where the operator can set different settings for different goals.

On the other hand, there is another actionCreateAjax in SettingCatController (setting-cat/create-ajax) which will allow the operator to create various categories.

In default/create (which render the Setting page) the operator can set setting category by a Modal form based on setting-cat/create-ajax by pjax but it doesn't work and nothing will send by trigging the submit button in Modal form!

I'd surfed different section for a long time and I'm sure the Asset Bundles were set right but I couldn't find the problem :(

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

PS: if someone needs more information, please tell me I will share more information.

**SettingCatController/actionCreateAjax:**

```
public function actionCreateAjax()
{
    $model = new SettingCategory();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return [
            'status' => 'success',
            'category' => ['id' => $model->id, 'title' => $model->title]
        ];
    }

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**SettingCatController/performAjaxValidation:**

```
protected function performAjaxValidation(Model $model, $attributes = null)
{
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        \Yii::$app->response->data = ActiveForm::validate($model, $attributes);
        \Yii::$app->response->send();
        \Yii::$app->end();
    }
}
```

**DefaultController/actionCreate(View):**

```
<div class="setting-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'dynamic-settings',
        'options' => ['data' => ['action' => 'save-setting']]
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'cat_id', [
                    'template' => "{label}\n
                                    <div class='input-group mb-3'>
                                        {input}
                                        <div class='input-group-append'>
                                        <span data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add-category-modal' data-action='add-category'
                                        data-url=\"" . Url::to(['/moresettings/setting-cat/create-ajax']) . "\" >
                                            <button class='btn btn-success' type='button' data-toggle='tooltip' 
                                            title=\"" . Yii::t('more-settings', 'Create new category!') . "\" >
                                                <i class='fas fa-plus'></i>
                                            </button>

                                        </div>
                                        {hint}\n{error}
                                    </div>",
                ]
                    </div>
                        </div>
                             </div>
                                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**DefaultController/actionCreate(Jquery/Pjax Part):**

```
    <?php
    Pjax::end();
    ?>

    <?php
    $loadingTag = CustomHtmlHelper::loadingTag();
    $loadingText = Yii::t('app', 'Loading ...');

    Modal::begin([
        'id' => 'add-category-modal',
        'size' => Modal::SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE,
        'bodyOptions' => [
            'id' => 'create-form-container',
            'class' => 'bg-light',
        ]
    ]);

    echo $loadingTag;

    Modal::end();

    $js = <<< JS

    jQuery('#dynamic-settings .select-type').on('change', function(event){
        resetFields(this); // lib.js
    });

     resetFields($('#dynamic-settings .select-type')); // lib.js

            var modalAddCategory = $('#add-category-modal');
            modalAddCategory.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                var button = $(e.relatedTarget)

                var pjaxSettings = {
                    timeout: 20000,
                    scrollTo: false,
                    push: false,
                    skipOuterContainers: true,
                    url: button.data('url'),
                    container: '#create-form-container'
                };

                $('#create-form-container').off('pjax:error');
                $('#create-form-container').on('pjax:error', function (event, xhr, textStatus, error, options) {
                    swal({
                        title: xhr.responseText,
                        type: "error",
                        confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up font-22"></i>',
                    });
                    return false;
                });            
                $('#create-form-container').off('pjax:complete');
                $('#create-form-container').on('pjax:complete', function (event, xhr, textStatus, options) {
                  modalAddCategory.off('submit', 'form');
                  modalAddCategory.on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
                    var submitBtn = $(this).find(':submit');
                    var submitBtnOldHtml = submitBtn.html();
                    submitBtn.attr('disabled', true).text('$loadingText');
                    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                            var newOption = new Option(data.category.title, data.category.id, true, true);
                            $(newOption).html(data.category.title);
                            $("#settings-cat_id").append(newOption).trigger('change');
                            modalAddCategory.modal('hide');
                        }
                        // errors handling
                        else {
                            $('#setting-cat-form').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', data, true);
                        }
                    }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                        submitBtn.attr('disabled', false).text(submitBtnOldHtml);
                        swal({
                            title: xhr.responseText,
                            type: "error",
                            confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up font-22"></i>',
                        });
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        submitBtn.attr('disabled', false).text(submitBtnOldHtml);
                    });
                    return false;
                  })
                });
                $.pjax(pjaxSettings);
            });

            modalAddCategory.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
              $(this).find('.modal-body').html('$loadingTag');
            });

    JS;

    $this->registerJs($js, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

**SettingCatController/actionCreateAjax(the View Which Is Showen In Modal Form of DefaultController/actionCreate):**

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;

    ?>

    <div class="setting-cat-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'setting-cat-form'
        ]); ?>

      //the fileds

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('more-settings', 'Create') : Yii::t('more-settings', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: A guess only. Perhaps it should be `type='submit'` instead of `type='button'`.

Comment: @GytisTenovimas the button will open the modal, so type='submit' isn't correct :(

Comment: Do you get anything in the browser console?  Did you "use" like this **use yii\bootstrap\Modal;** ?

Comment: @Mike There isn't any error in console and yii\bootstrap4\Modal is defined

Comment: Here's a link to a modal link directly copied from the HTML of one of my forms **<a href="/admin/web/index.php?r=users%2Fupdate&amp;id=2260" title="Update" aria-label="Update" data-pjax="0" role="modal-remote" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>**.  This is a pencil icon, is calling the wrong modal and you don't need the tooltip so for you it might be something like this **<a href="' . Url::to(['/moresettings/setting-cat/create-ajax']) . '" data-pjax="0" role="add-category-modal" class='btn btn-success'></a>**

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately it doesn't work as 'href' redirects the page to create-ajax action without modal